# XSLT : Remove child nodes without repeating XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Transaction>
    <Product>
        <ProductRq>
            <ContactInfo>
                <!-- several child elements -->
            </ContactInfo>
            <OrderInfo>
                <!-- several child elements -->
            </OrderInfo>
            <ProductInfo>
                <!-- several child elements -->
            </ProductInfo>
            <AddressInfo>
                <!-- several child elements -->
            </AddressInfo>
            <AuditInfo>
                <!-- several child elements -->
            </AuditInfo>
            <DeliveryInfo>
                <!-- several child elements -->
            </DeliveryInfo>
        </ProductRq>
    </Product>
</Transaction>
```

For sake of brevity I've left out several more children to the `<ProductRq>` tag, which contains 4 or 5 more child elements akin to `<OrderInfo>` and `<CustomerInfo>`, as well as the child nodes of the *Info elements.

I need to remove the children of the elements like Order and `<CustomerInfo>` while retaining the *Info tag. Out of the 7 tags, around 4 are to be put through this process. I can't think of how to do this without repeating:

```
<xsl:template match="Transcation/Product/ProductRq/<tag name here>/*" />
```

for each child of `<ProductRq>`. Is there a way to leverage the context node(`<ProductRq>`) and sort of loop through the children, removing their own child nodes aside from the above?

EDIT:
I added the remaining child tags of `<ProductRq>`. All tags except `<AuditInfo>` and `<ContactInfo>` must have their child nodes removed.

Comment: You don't actually need to specify the full xpath in a template match, you can just do `<xsl:template match="<tag name here>/*" />`. You would only need to qualify it with a full path if the same element could occur in different levels in the hierarchy and you needed to distinguish them.

Comment: well I think there's a chance a few of the child elements of ProductRq could repeat for different tags further down the document, but ProducerRq is unique, so ProducerRq/<tag name> would suffice?

Comment: @jbailie1991 - you really will need to show those omitted children as they are very relevant to your question. Show at least the children of *ProductRq*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is applying the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">                
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- skip all child nodes of ProductRq except they are AuditInfo or ContactInfo -->
  <xsl:template match="ProductRq/*[not(self::AuditInfo | self::ContactInfo)]">       
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" />   <!-- so create an element with this name -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Transaction>
    <Product>
        <ProductRq>
            <ContactInfo>
                <!-- several child elements -->
            </ContactInfo>
            <OrderInfo/>
            <ProductInfo/>
            <AddressInfo/>
            <AuditInfo>
                <!-- several child elements -->
            </AuditInfo>
            <DeliveryInfo/>
        </ProductRq>
    </Product>
</Transaction>
```

Comment: so the third template, If I understand correctly, matches child nodes of ProductRq that aren't AuditInfo or ContactInfo, then checks the element name isn't empty and if not, create a new element with that name? so more or less overwriting the matched elements with the same tag except its empty?

Comment: @jbailie1991: You're right. After reading your comment I also removed the superfluous second template from the answer. So the last (former 3rd) template just recreates all elements that are not `AuditInfo` or `ContactInfo` (and are of no other node type (name()=empty)) without any child nodes.

Comment: ah ok that's pretty cool. So those child nodes would always be there, even if empty, so could this go one further and drop the conditional?Just replace each found element with a blank version?

Comment: @jbailie1991: I further improved my answer by replacing `ProductRq/node()[...]` by `ProductRq/*[...]`. This way only elements (and not all nodes) got selected and so the `<xsl:if...` check for empty nodes becomes superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to remove the children of the elements like `Order` and
>   `<CustomerInfo>` while retaining the *Info tag.

The template you are looking for is

```
<!-- XSLT 2.0 and up -->
<xsl:template match="ProductRq/*[ends-with(name(), 'Info')]/*" />


<!-- XSLT 1.0 variant, as ends-with() does not exist here -->
<xsl:template match="ProductRq/*[
  substring-before(name(), 'Info') != '' and substring-after(name(), 'Info') = ''
]/*" />
```

Comment: I like the xslt 2 one liner, but that would remove all children of all elements ending in Info. For my use case, I need to retain the child elements of AuditInfo and ContactInfo, and strip the child nodes of the other *Info tags

Comment: @jbailie1991 That's easy, just add the exceptions to the expression like this `and not(name() = 'KeepThis' or name() = 'KeepThat')`.

Comment: @jbailie1991 Any feedback on my answer? Have you tried further? Did it work? If not, what did not work?

Comment: I went with the answer above. It allowed me to strip children of ProductRq child elements without removing the actual child itself, along with skipping the exceptions outlined in the question, whereas this removed all child elements, and even with the method of adding exceptions that you posted it would still remove the tags entirely rather than remove the childrens children but keep the empty tag

Answer (score 0):

Write a template matching `ProductRq`:

```
<xsl:template match="ProductRq">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ContactInfo | OrderInfo | ProductInfo | AddressInfo"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As you see, the `select` clause contains all child nodes, which are to be included.
By default it performs a deep copy (with child nodes).

But you wrote that some nodes (e.g. `ContactInfo` and `OrderInfo`) are to be copied only in the shallow mode.
(I assume that this mode should involve copying only child text nodes
but nothing more. Copying of "empty" tags seems a weird concept.)

In order to have only shallow copy of these nodes, write another tempate:

```
<xsl:template match="ContactInfo | OrderInfo">
  <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To sum up, you write names of nodes involved (separated with "|") in 2 places:

- all names is the first template,
- names of nodes to be shallow copied in the second template.

Somewhere you have to write these names anyway.

Comment: I see, so I would specify all ProductRqs child nodes in the 1st template, and define which nodes I want the children stripped from in the 2nd template? Also, the empty tags, those are for a downstream system. I'm not 100% on why they want a <myTag /> in the xml, but I'm guessing its for additional processing(possibly validation; my service is not required to as it sits between 2 queues, its sole job is to transform xml for other systems depending on a header attached to an Exchange object